# Issue class coercion filtered R data.table ifelse, if_else, if ... else

Tags: r, data.table

I am encountering problems with R data.table, while converting a character variable to a numeric variable based on some conditions:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(a = "A", b = "B")
DT2 <- data.table(a = "A", b = "B")

DT1[a == "A", b := ifelse(b == "B", 1, 0)]    #option 1: incorrect behavior
DT2[,         b := ifelse(b == "B", 1, 0)]    #option 2: correct behavior
```

Expected correct output:

```
   a             b
1: A (character) 1 (numeric)
```

However, with option 1 I am getting the following output (with a warning):

```
   a             b
1: A (character) 1 (character)
```

> Warning message:
>
> In `[.data.table`(DT1, a == "A", `:=`(b, ifelse(b == "B", 1, 0))) :
>
> Coerced double RHS to character to match the type of the target column (column 2 named 'b'). If the target column's type character is correct, it's best for efficiency to avoid the coercion and create the RHS as type character. To achieve that consider R's type postfix: typeof(0L) vs typeof(0), and typeof(NA) vs typeof(NA_integer_) vs typeof(NA_real_). You can wrap the RHS with as.character() to avoid this warning, but that will still perform the coercion. If the target column's type is not correct, it's best to revisit where the DT was created and fix the column type there; e.g., by using colClasses= in fread(). Otherwise, you can change the column type now by plonking a new column (of the desired type) over the top of it; e.g. DT[, `b`:=as.double(`b`)]. If the RHS of := has nrow(DT) elements then the assignment is called a column plonk and is the way to change a column's type. Column types can be observed with sapply(DT,typeof).

Q: Can somebody explain me why option 1 does not work? Does this seem like a bug to you?

---

Extra's:
it is obviously also possible to do the following:

```
DT3 <- data.table(a = "A", b = "B")
DT3[, b := ifelse(a == "A" & b == "B", 1, 0)] #option 3: correct behavior
```

However, I prefer option 1 over option 3 because I would like to keep the variable logic & filter logic separate.

Note: the issue also arises when replacing ifelse with dplyr::if_else or base::if...else

Comment: Note there is a new function `fifelse`, a replacement for `ifelse`. Try `data.table::update.dev.pkg()` to upgrade data.table to latest version.

Comment: `fifelse` gives lot of pain when the class is unknown or is computed on the fly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes have a hierarchy - `character` is more general than `numeric`. If you assign a `character` to (part) of a numeric vector, it's safe to convert the whole vector to `character`, because numerics can be represented as `character`.

In this case, you assign a `numeric` to part of a `character` vector, and `data.table` has the option to either

- (a) check the whole vector (column) to see if it's safe to convert to numeric (expensive, and perhaps unexpected and surprising to users)
- (b) convert the numeric value to character.

My guess is that when you use `DT1[a == "A", ...]`, the internals assume that you are assigning to only *part* of the vector, even when your condition happens to match every row. So `data.table` performs the efficient and safe (b) option above and converts your `numeric` to a `character`.

On the other hand, the syntax `DT2[, b := ifelse(b == "B", 1, 0)]` overwrites the entire `b` column - it doesn't matter what was there before, you're putting a `numeric` there now.

I think the real lesson is that, if you want to change the class of a column you should do it explicitly rather than relying on automatic conversion based on assigning new values to a part of the column.